# CUDA: Copying arrays to GPU

Tags: c, cuda

I am trying to create a function which allocates and copies values to an array on the device.  For some reason the code works fine inline but not when I put it in a function as follows.  Am I passing the parameters correctly?

My CUDA program still executes (without error) however if I read back the values I have written they seem to be undefined ie. not the original values from HostArray.

```
void CopyArrayToGPU(double *DeviceArray, double *HostArray, int NumElements)
{
    int bytes = sizeof(double) * NumElements;

    // Allocate memory on the GPU for array
    if (cudaMalloc((void**)&DeviceArray, bytes) != cudaSuccess)
    {
        printf("CopyArrayToGPU(): Couldn't allocate mem for array on GPU.");
    }

    // Copy the contents of the host array to the GPU
    if (cudaMemcpy(DeviceArray, HostArray, bytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) != cudaSuccess)
    {
        printf("CopyArrayToGPU(): Couldn't copy host array to GPU.");
    }
}

// Declare device side array
static double *d_Inputs;

// Allocate host side array and plug in some test values
double *testArray = (double*)malloc(ImageSize);
testArray[0] = 0.6455696203; testArray[1] = 0.7954545455; testArray[2] = 0.2028985507; testArray[3] = 0.08;

CopyArrayToGPU(d_Inputs, testArray, NUM_INPUTS * NUM_ROWS);
```

Comment: Read [mcve]. We need to know how do you call `CopyArrayToGPU`. Probably `DeviceArray` that is locale to your function.

Comment: I have included some more code in my question and I believe that it is sufficient to answer whether or not I am calling the function correctly.

Comment: What is `ImageSize`, `NUM_INPUTS` and `NUM_ROWS`? Why to you cast return of malloc in C? What is the output of your program with your `printf()`? Does it show "CopyArrayToGPU(): Couldn't allocate mem for array on GPU." or/and "CopyArrayToGPU(): Couldn't copy host array to GPU."?

Comment: As I said the program works without error except that the correct values don't get written to the GPU (as in HostArray).  I get -6277438562....  instead.

Comment: You said "My CUDA program still executes however" you don't say they are no error. Whatever I think that my answer will fix your problem. Note that I can't test so maybe this will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable `DeviceArray` is **locale** to your function.

You must take a `double **DeviceArray` as argument or return the value that have been allocate by cuda.

Return value version:

```
double *CopyArrayToGPU(double *HostArray, int NumElements)
{
    int bytes = sizeof(double) * NumElements;
    void *DeviceArray;

    // Allocate memory on the GPU for array
    if (cudaMalloc(&DeviceArray, bytes) != cudaSuccess)
    {
        printf("CopyArrayToGPU(): Couldn't allocate mem for array on GPU.");
        return NULL;
    }

    // Copy the contents of the host array to the GPU
    if (cudaMemcpy(DeviceArray, HostArray, bytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) != cudaSuccess)
    {
        printf("CopyArrayToGPU(): Couldn't copy host array to GPU.");
        cudaFree(DeviceArray);
        return NULL;
    }

    return DeviceArray;
}
```

So you must call it like:

```
d_Inputs = CopyArrayToGPU(testArray, NUM_INPUTS * NUM_ROWS);
```

---

`double **DeviceArray` as argument version:

```
int CopyArrayToGPU(double **DeviceArray, double *HostArray, int NumElements)
{
    int bytes = sizeof(double) * NumElements;

    // Allocate memory on the GPU for array
    if (cudaMalloc((void **)DeviceArray, bytes) != cudaSuccess)
    {
        printf("CopyArrayToGPU(): Couldn't allocate mem for array on GPU.");
        return 1;
    }

    // Copy the contents of the host array to the GPU
    if (cudaMemcpy(*DeviceArray, HostArray, bytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) != cudaSuccess)
    {
        printf("CopyArrayToGPU(): Couldn't copy host array to GPU.");
        cudaFree(*DeviceArray);
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So you must call it like:

```
CopyArrayToGPU(&d_Inputs, testArray, NUM_INPUTS * NUM_ROWS);
```

Comment: Thankyou, this is a big help.  But when you say return the value allocated by cuda what does that mean?  Is that from cudaMalloc?

Comment: @PaulMatthews [`cudaMalloc`](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15668-s11/www/cuda-doc/html/group__CUDART__MEMORY_gc63ffd93e344b939d6399199d8b12fef.html) allocate memory in `DeviceArray` your function need to return the value... You should read some book of C this is basic.

Comment: Yes I have not spent much time with C.  I believe that void *DeviceArray should be double *DeviceArray to be correct return type.

Comment: @PaulMatthews I declare it with `void *` because I don't want to cast. You dont use `DeviceArray` as `double *` in the function `CopyArrayToGPU`. It's a choice they are many other way.